# Explode reply after group concat

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

The only way i've managed to get replies from the reply table is thru group concat but all the replies appear in one line. I need each reply to appear per row. I have tried to explode it various ways after the mysql query. Most of the explode codes i find only work with echo and do not work with a row. Is their a way to explode it or another way to separate the reply. Basically once i group the reply to a post/image only one reply appears but when i group concate all the replies appear but only in one row. I've managed to separate them by spaces or commas but they still stay in one line.

```
<?php  


   $sql = "     
 SELECT images.mid, images.id, images.who, header.username, images.message, images.name, GROUP_CONCAT(reply.reply
 SEPARATOR 0x1E ) as heat
FROM header, images
LEFT JOIN reply ON reply.reply = reply.mid
 OR reply.mid = images.mid
WHERE images.name IS NOT NULL = header.id
AND images.who IS NOT NULL 
AND images.message IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY images.mid
";

$rs = mysql_query( $sql );

 while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs )

  ) {



   $name = $row['name'];

    $mid = $row['mid'];
   $title = $row['title'];
   $who = $row['who'];
$details = $row['details'];
$message = $row['message'];
$id = $row['id'];
    $heat = explode(',', $row['heat']);
  $heat = array (".",$row['heat']);
   foreach($heat as $heat)



 $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

  if($row){
            $name= $row['name'];


  ?>

   <td>

        <table>

                 <tr>
               <td>
   <a href="a/<?=$name ?>" rel='lightbox' title='$timestamp - $message'> <img src=     "a/<?=$name ?>" width='150' height='100'" >  </a>  </td> 
                     </tr>



                    <tr> <td> <?=$row['name'] ?> 
                     </td> </tr>

                      <tr>
  <td>    <?=$row['who'] ?> </td> </tr>
                     <tr>
  <td> <?=$row['message'] ?></td> </tr>
                    <tr>
   <td>   <?=$row['id'] ?></td> </tr>
                      <tr>
<td>   <?=$row['mid'] ?> </td> </tr>
                        <tr>
  <td>   <?=$row['username'] ?></td>
                </tr><tr>
 <td>  <?=$row['heat'] ?></td>  


                   </tr>  

       </table>

    </td>
 <?
}
        else{
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; //If there are no more records at the end, add a blank column
        }

} while($row);
echo "</table>";


  ?>


    </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

This is the result i get for the replies with group concat is.

```
   She fell, she ate, she came, its good, okay.
```

I've managed to turn this into an array also but than i get stuck on that also. 
For those who know CSS. Is their a way to throw an array of data into rows. I remember seeing it but can't remember  how to do it.

Comment: you have to loop over the list of replies a second time and print a new row for each one.  it looks like you're trying to do that, but using `mysql_fetch_array` a second time inside the inner loop?  why?

Comment: but you don't _want_ them to all appear in a row, right?  maybe i'm misunderstanding your problem.  this indentation is very hard to read

Comment: you know. I think you do have a point there. Why did i have two loop arrays. Maybe that was the problem.

Comment: thanks Eevee, You pointed out something good in a really complicated code that a few people have answers too. I'm getting different results right now excluding that extra loop array and have to figure out now how to explode correclty.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop: you're calling `mysql_fetch_array` a second time in your inner loop and referring to `$row['heat']`, instead of using the `$heat` you already have and split.  Remove the second fetch and use `$heat`.  :)

Comment: that is not the answer. Thats the only way to explode or you might say the only results you'll get when you explode an array from group concat